# Starship IFT-3: Plasma appears, then disappears

Tags: reentry, spacex-starship

[image]

How is that possible? It's not like it lost velocity or gained altitude in that time period.

Answer (score 25):

Notice how the ship is rolling uncontrollably during reentry -- it should be presenting the heat shield in a "belly first" orientation, but something clearly went wrong, because even before reentry starts, the ship is rotating significantly, and it never stops from there to the end of the video feed. Even though we're seeing plasma forming, at that altitude (90+ km) there isn't enough atmosphere to give them control authority through the winglets, and there's no sign of thrusters firing since just after engine cutoff. (There was a lot of gas coming out of the ship at that time, which may have been intentionally draining the tanks, but it's possible something happened at that point that drained all their thruster fuel as well, like a stuck valve that kept one thruster firing continuously.) In any case, whatever the reason, during reentry the ship is spinning and can't stop.

Around T+46:30 the ship is in the proper orientation, but from the movement of the clouds below it's clear that by T+46:45 the winglet we can see is no longer in the airstream; it's now in the "shadow" of the body.

Over the next minute, the camera's view gets pretty badly obscured but it looks to me like Starship pitched around to start presenting engines-first -- the visible plasma flows appear to be coming up from around the engines towards the camera -- and then the transmission breaks up, which I suspect was not a loss of signal, but rather the camera itself burning up.

The plasma is always coming from the prograde direction, it's just that where prograde is relative to the camera's fixed perspective keeps changing.

Comment: I find it amazing that there is enough of an atmosphere above the Kármán line to create a visible plasma at all!

Comment: There's still enough at ISS's 400km that it needs reboosting about once a month.

Comment: Also interesting: Above around 100km, the atmosphere stops being a turbulent fluid and the mean free path of the air molecules grows dramatically. But *at* 100 km, it is still only 16 cm which, I suppose, is necessary to see the glow (because the molecules bouncing off Starship need to collide with other air molecules or there would be no effect). Btw, the temperature corresponding to Nitrogen molecules at 7200 m/s is some 34,000 K, if I operate [this calculator](https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/particles-velocity) correctly.

Answer (score 4):

It's probably due to changes in the orientation of Starship, by roll, pitch or yaw. This could easily change the flow of the highly tenuous gas over the ship at the start of re-entry. As it gets further into the atmosphere this gets progressively harder as the pressure increases there is a lot more gas and heat to deal with.